# Is this native code possible for further static analysis?

Tags: ida, android, ghidra, java, apk

I was trying to reverse engineer a native lib code in an android app. the `.so` contains many functions. But the function `sUQWWyTBEs()` was referred in the Java code. I was curious how this function works, the code of the function `sUQWWyTBEs()` decompiled with `Ghidra`:

```
*************************************************************
                             *                           FUNCTION                          
                             *************************************************************
                             undefined  __cdecl  Myapp_sUQWWyTBEs()
             undefined         w0:1           <RETURN>
             longlong *        x0:8           param_1
                             Myapp_sUQWWyTBEs XREF[2]:     Entry Point (*) , 00101350   
        00100e44 08  00  40  f9    ldr        x8, [param_1 ]
        00100e48 01  00  00  b0    adrp       x1, s_c7a584936712f32773d3d0a_00101000           ; = "c7a584936712f32773d3d0a"
        00100e4c 21  60  08  91    add        x1, x1, #0x218
        00100e50 02  9d  42  f9    ldr        x2, [x8, #0x538 ]
        00100e54 40  00  1f  d6    br         x2
```

in my understanding, I have made the static analysis as like following:

`00100e44 08  00  40  f9    ldr        x8, [param_1 ]`

load the value at memory address param_1 into register x8.

`0100e48 01  00  00  b0    adrp       x1, s_c7a584936712f32773d3d0a_00101000`

sets register x1 to 0x101000.

`00100e4c 21  60  08  91    add        x1, x1, #0x218`

adds 0x218 to x1, so it sets x1 to 0x101218.

`00100e50 02  9d  42  f9    ldr        x2, [x8, #0x538 ]`

loads the value at x8 + 0x538 into x2.

`00100e54 40  00  1f  d6    br         x2`

and finally branches to the  address stored in `x2`.

with that being said, Here I don't know the memory at address at `x2`, obviously it initially  depends on the value `param_1` holds. is there way or how can I refer where `param_1` was initialized? I don't know very much about usage of `Ghidra` or other reverse engineering tools. any one might help would be appreciated.

Edit: **This function returns a string like this `47fjlkj843h9asjklj94kljfsad93j4l2715943hasd...` but what I wanted is that how this value was generated or returned.**

Comment: If this is a function called from Java the first step is to look at the Java declaration of the method what parameters it has. On native side the first parameter of a JNI function should be the pointer to the JNI environment providing a lot of methods for Java native conversions.

Comment: @Robert at the at entry this code appears:    `00100ca0 00  00  00  d0    adrp      param_1, 0x102000`
        `00100ca4 00  20  37  91    add        param_1=>PTR_LOOP_00102dc8 , param_1, #0xdc8`  the param_1 was done like this. but value it is holding btw?

Comment: so param_1 appears to be holding jni env and being used as a frame pointer.

Comment: My guess would be that `#538` is the offset to function `newStringUTF`. For offsets in 32bit see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yqjFaY7mqyVIDs5jNjGLT-G8pUaRATzHWGFUgpdJRq8/edit#gid=0. I would assume that your binary is 64bit, thus the references are double the value of this spread sheet.

Comment: @Robert I have loaded the code into JEB decompiler and it outputs as [link](https://pastebin.com/AUSyXN0j). JEB comments each instruction's output but I wanted how the output was generated?

Comment: any explanation how `LDR`, `ADRP` and `ADD` are working in this context? thanks,

Comment: `LDR` is simple. JNIEnv in C is a struct. The pointer to JNIEnv is loaded into x8 without offset (first ldr). Later the offset #538 is added (second ldr) so that x2 now contains the pointer to the method `newStringUTF` which is then executed. For ADRP read https://stackoverflow.com/q/41906688/150978. Why `0x218` is added depends on the data at the pointers_c7a584936712f32773d3d0a_00101000.

Comment: adding `0x218` to `x1` yields `0x101218`, a same memory address that contains the string returned I was talking above: this is the address `00001218   a47fjlkj843h9asj db "47fjlkj843h9asjklj94kljfsad93j4l2715943hasdlkas93j99",0` I completely lost next steps so this data was passed to `newStringUTF` function?